# Why can't I send an email message?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am faced with the fact that I can not send an email message. I can not understand the reason. I use Spting Boot 2. The example uses the JavaMailSender class. But you can do without its implementation and the necessary parameters to be specified in the application.properties?

```
@Configuration
public class MainConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.yandex.ru");
        mailSender.setPort(465);

        mailSender.setUsername("test@yandex.ru");
        mailSender.setPassword("test122223");

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", 1000);

        return mailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMailMessage templateSimpleMessage() {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setText("This is the test email template for your email:");
        return message;
    }

}
```

And after 2 min, i'm have it's error: `"javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host"`

Comment: Make sure you can actually send an SMTP message to that mail server from whatever machine you're running it on.  Due to issues with spammers, most mail servers aren't going to just accept mail from any old source that tries anymore.  If you can get access to the mail server log, you might get more hints there as well.

Comment: @Gus i'm can create email message from my old project without spring. In old project not problem...

Comment: Get of the [socket factory settings](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) and post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
```

or

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
```

I didn't get why are you using a Configuration class, if you are using spring boot 2 you could just put all the email configuration in your application.properties file:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
spring.mail.host=smtp.yandex.ru
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=test@yandex.ru
spring.mail.password=test122223
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   i.setType("message/rfc822");
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try{
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
   }
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
     Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

Comment: An explanation as to WHY this would fix the issue would have made it abundantly obvious that this in fact does NOT fix the issue.